# Built-in way to cast a string that is a a binary number to an actual number in Rust?

Tags: rust

For instance:

```
let n = "1010";

let m: u32 = ?
```

It can be done by adding each digit multiplied by the right power of two but is there another, simpler, built-in way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_str_radix), available to all 
core integer types.

```
let n = "1010";
let m = u32::from_str_radix(n, 2)?;
assert_eq!(m, 10);
```